# Loading CSV into GraphX with Vertex Attributes

Tags: csv, spark-graphx

I'm new to GraphX and I'm trying to load a CSV file as a graph. The CSV is in the format:

```
ID1      ID2      Attr1     Attr2      OtherAttr1      OtherAttr2
0        6        -2        4          soccer          basketball
3        1        5         -3         coke            software
1        0        -3        -2         software        soccer
.
.
.
```

The first two columns represent the IDs of the vertices, and the link is between the first one (ID1) and the second one (ID2). `Attr1` and `OtherAttr1` are attributes of vertex 1 (`ID1`), and `Attr2` and `OtherAttr2` are the attributes of vertex 2 (`ID2`).

So, in my graph I'd have 0 pointing towards 6, where 0 has attributes -2 and soccer, and 6 has attributes 4 and basketball. Then 3 points towards 1, and so on.

Also note that the attributes are consistent with the vertex, so even though vertex with ID 1 appears twice, its attributes are consistent in both rows.

Please help me out, and if there's a better way to make the table itself that'll make it easier, then please let me know!

Comment: are you asking how to format the csv differently to make loading as easy as possible? Or how to load a csv with the format you describe?

Comment: I was asking how to load the CSV with the format described, but also wanted to know if other formats would make it easier to load. Anyways, I figured it out :)